# Angular Primeng Datatable Paginator Bottom Anchoring

Tags: angular, datatable, primeng

I have a Datatable with a paginator in bottom position.
Say it has to show 22 record per page, 26 records total.
In the second page the paginator is positioned right under the last 4 records, and not at the very bottom of the area assigned to the grid (under the 22th potential record). I don't think this is the good way to handle it, because the user sees the pages selector "disappear" under his mouse arrow, and he has to move up if he wants to get back to the previous page. 
Is there a way to anchor the paginator always at the very bottom of the grid? I didn't find anything in the documentation.
Thanks, Giovanni

Answer (score 0):

I can't be sure because I'm new to PrimeNG, but you can try adding simple CSS for this class:

```css
.ui-datatable-tablewrapper{
    max-height: 300px;
    overflow: auto;
}
```

Comment: I ended up positioning the paginator in top position. Quite simple, but I didn't think of this solution at the beginning. I still keep thinking that, for the bottom paginator, that kind of behaviour is wrong.